# Why does everything but the side-menu adjust for a mobile screen?

Tags: html, css

This website I'm updating, all the fonts and icons, images etc adjust for the screen size. But for some reason the side-menu doesn't appear on my Samsung s4, I have to scroll to the right to find it. But on desktop it adjusts perfectly fine no matter how I resize the browser window. I should mention that I am using Chrome on my s4, I tested it on the mobile "Browser" app and it works fine there. [Website](http://convio.cancer.ca/site/PageServer?pagename=%2FUFE_ON_Custom_2016#)

Even [MobileTest](http://mobiletest.me/htc_one_emulator/?u=http://convio.cancer.ca/site/PageServer?pagename=%2FUFE_ON_Custom_2016#) website displays it fine. But when I test it on my Chrome mobile browser, or my colleagues iPhone 5s browser, the menu is pushed to the side and you have to swipe left to see it.

here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqx2kypv/3/) but for some reason the menu doesn't even appear there.

***Edit*** I made the menu fixed to the screen so that it scrolls vertically with the user.

HTML:

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="menu-close" href="#)" class="btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#top"  onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >The Society</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#top" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >About the event</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#services" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Find a participant</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#register" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Register</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#donate" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Donate</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
<div class="blackbar">
<img src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mUFE/2016/one/img/CCS_En_WebSafe.gif" alt="Canadian Cancer Society" height="55" width="191" /> 
</div>
<header id="top" class="header">
<div class="text-vertical-center">
            <h1>Event Title</h1>
            <h3>Tag Line</h3>
            <br>
            <a href="#about" class="btn-dark btn-lg">Learn More</a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

   <!-- Log In -->
<ul>
         <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="http://phpoll.com/login" class="dropdown-toggle btn-dark btn-lg" data-toggle="dropdown">Log In</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-lr animated flipInX" role="menu">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="text-verticle-center">
                <h5><b>Log In</b></h5></div>         

              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
     font-family: DaxRegular !important;    
}     

p {
   font-family: DaxLight !important;
}


a {
  text-decoration: none !important;

}

.bg-primary {
    background-color: #0066CC !important;
}

.text-vertical-center {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-vertical-center h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.text-vertical-center h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 5.5em;
    font-weight: 700;

}

/* Side Menu */

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #222;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 55px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 55px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

#menu-toggle {
    z-index: 101;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper.active {
    right: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.toggle {
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

/* Header */

.header {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
background: url(http://convio.cancer.ca/mUFE/2016/one/img/cliffside.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;

}

.header h1 {
    font-size: 5.5em;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(0,0,0);
}

.header h3{
    font-size: 4em;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(0,0,0);
}

.header h4{
    font-size: 6.5em;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(0,0,0);
}    
</style>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of errors on your website.

First : change your `#menu-toggle from fixed to absolute` and it seems like doing the trick to keep the button on the page ( withought having to scroll right )

**BUT**

At this point you still can scroll right and this is caused because you fixed pretty much everything and `width:100%;` is known for having this kind of issues.
You should fix all the errors you have in your HTML and try to make your `div` float. It should fix the white space on the right.

**Edit :** Your are hiding `sidebar-wrapper` on the right of your screen. This is also not the best option when you can simply use `display:none;` If the white space on the right doesn't bother you, change his position from `fixed to absolute` exactly as `#menu-toggle`

Comment: sorry i failed to mention, the reason i had menu toggle as fixed is because I wanted it to scroll vertically with the page so that the user can access it anytime.

Comment: This is weird, in portrait mode on the mobile browser I get that whitespace issue, but in landscape I don't. Why is it that the `width: 100%` is causing this? none of my other divs are fixed, or are using any positioning. Only the sidebar-nav is fixed. I checked the validation tool a lot of those errors are from the CMS stuff that I cannot edit unfortunately.

Comment: Because the white space problem is most likely happening because an element size is 100% and there is another element having a size like 5px at his right. The chrome console is telling that there are errors that could result in an unexpected behavior, it could be that too.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did but it seems to be working on a few other pages except this one, which is okay because those pages are launching soon. Followed your instructions and it's working, thanks a lot Relisora!

Comment: Happy for being able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

clean the errors in your html code to start [html validation](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fconvio.cancer.ca%2Fsite%2FPageServer%3Fpagename%3D%252FUFE_ON_Custom_2016)
you also have `<!DOCTYPE html>` twice, once at the top and then again way down below the css. 
Your css has errors [css validation](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fconvio.cancer.ca%2Fsite%2FPageServer%3Fpagename%3D%252FUFE_ON_Custom_2016%23&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)
 and in the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`  is from HTML4, you should use `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: good call on the html validation totally forgot about that. and the Doctype what a silly mistake, this CMS I'm using is so confusing didn't even state that it would make all of that stuff already lol. Thanks for this!